# Convert brightcove.com embedded flashplayer for use for mobile?

Tags: media-player, brightcove

A client has a link to a brightcove.com video. The client didn't create the video and the company that doesn't have a technical staff to help. The embedded code looks something like this:

```
    <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f8/1234567890" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId= 1234567890&playerId= 1234567890&viewerSecureGatewayURL=https://console.brightcove.com/services/amfgateway&servicesURL=http://services.brightcove.com/services&cdnURL=http://admin.brightcove.com&domain=embed&autoStart=false&" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="465" height="335" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
```

It plays OK for Desktop systems but it doesn't work for mobile because it's FLASH. Is there a way to modify this to pass parameters so it uses a player that works with mobile? We don't have access to the original video so we can't upload it there or any place else, so we are trying to simply make what is there work for mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A URL like that with "federated_f8" is a really old version of Brightcove's player for which there is no mobile version. You will need to get the 'javascript publishing code' for a current player from the Brightcove Video Cloud account.